# Validate page parameter in Server Side Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a razor component page that accepts a parameter.

```
@page "/Customer/{CustomerId:int}"
```

Now I am checkking the method OnParametersSetAsync if the customerId exists. If it does not exists, I want to display/trigger 404 exception.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to create your own 404 page and redirect the user to it using `NavigationManager`

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/404");
```